# Face Recognition iPhone X Swift

Tags: swift, face-recognition, iphone-x

I done some experiments with ARFaceAnchor for recognize some emotions like blinking eyes and so on. For sure I set correctly the FaceAnchor because on the debugger I'm able to see the coordinates but it seems that it's not recognizing any emotions that I set...

Attached you will find the ViewController and in a separate Class you will find the Emotions.

Any ideas? Thank you!

```
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    let session = ARSession()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        self.sceneView.rendersContinuously = true

        // Configure our ARKit tracking session for facial recognition
        let config = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        config.worldAlignment = .gravity
        session.delegate = self
        session.run(config, options: [])
    }

    // AR Session

    var currentFaceAnchor: ARFaceAnchor?
    var currentFrame: ARFrame?

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        self.currentFrame = frame
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

        }
    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        guard let faceAnchor = anchors.first as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }
        self.currentFaceAnchor = faceAnchor
        print("Face",faceAnchor)

    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didRemove anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

    }

    var expressionsToUse: [Expression] = [SmileExpression(), EyebrowsRaisedExpression(), EyeBlinkLeftExpression(), EyeBlinkRightExpression(), JawOpenExpression(), LookLeftExpression(), LookRightExpression()] //All the expressions
    var currentExpression: Expression? = nil {
        didSet {
            if currentExpression != nil {
                self.currentExpressionShownAt = Date()
            } else {
                self.currentExpressionShownAt = nil
            }
        }
    }
    var currentExpressionShownAt: Date? = nil



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason no Expressions are being detected is because you aren't actually doing anything with them, apart from adding them to `expressionsToUse` Array.

Each `Expression` has three functions, which you aren't currently using:

```
 func name() -> String {}
 func isExpressing(from: ARFaceAnchor) -> Bool {}
 func isDoingWrongExpression(from: ARFaceAnchor) -> Bool {}
```

Since you want to detect the Emotions you need to hook these functions into the following delegate method:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) { }
```

As such something like this will point you in the right direction:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

    //1. Check To See We Have A Valid ARFaceAnchor
    guard let faceAnchor = anchors.first as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }

    self.currentFaceAnchor = faceAnchor

    //2. Loop Through Each Of The Expression & Determine Which One Is Being Used
    expressionsToUse.forEach { (possibleExpression) in

        //a. If The The User Is Doing A Particular Expression Then Assign It To The currentExpression Variable
        if possibleExpression.isExpressing(from: faceAnchor){

            currentExpression = possibleExpression

            print("""
                  Current Detected Expression = \(possibleExpression.name())
                  It Was Detected On \(currentExpressionShownAt!)
                  """)

        }else if possibleExpression.isDoingWrongExpression(from: faceAnchor){

           print("Incorrect Detected Expression = \(possibleExpression.name())")
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: That's great! It's working perfectly... Thank you very much for your great help, really appreciated :)

Comment: Super helpful ! :) it was since June that I was stacked, then I switched and published other apps on the store and I totally forgot about this one!

Comment: Hi @BlackMirrorz :(((( could you help me with ARKit/scenekit 3D to 2D projection problem :(((